# Did my program cause a BSOD?

Tags: c++, windows, loops, bsod

So I have written a little tool which sends a keypress for a random duration at random intervals to get around the automatic logout because of inactivity in some games.
I wrote it today but while testing my computer suddenly gave me a BSOD (KMODE_Exception_Not_Handled). This is the first ever BSOD I encountered so I think it might be because of my program.

Main C++ file:

```
using namespace std;

class Activator;

int main()
{
    Activator *a = new Activator();

    cout << "It sends a random amount of arrow keypresses to the RSClient at random intervals." << endl
        << "Because of the randomness of this program it will be fairly safe to use but I take no responsability for your actions, after all it's still macroing/botting!" << endl
        << "Press any key to start KeepRSActive..." << endl;
    _getch();
    system("cls");

    for (size_t i = 10; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "Please click inside of your RS client" << endl << "The program will start in: " << i << " seconds." << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
    }
    cout << "You will no longer be bothered by automatic logouts!" << endl << "Simply close the console window to stop.";

    //Main program loop
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(33); //30 TPS, Basically a simple repeatable timer.
        a->tick();
    }

    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Activator.cpp

```
Activator::Activator()
{
    // Easier to randomise later on
    m_KeyList[0] = VK_LEFT;
    m_KeyList[1] = VK_RIGHT;
    m_KeyList[2] = VK_UP;
    m_KeyList[3] = VK_DOWN;
}

Activator::~Activator()
{

}

void Activator::tick()
{
    // Random key selected from m_KeyList
    setUpNewKeypress(rand() % ARRAYSIZE(m_KeyList) - 1);

    // Random amount of time between key presses
    Sleep((rand() % 200000) + 20000);
}

void Activator::setUpNewKeypress(WORD key)
{
    //Set up the keypress
    INPUT input;

    // Set up a keyboard event.
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wScan = 0;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Press the key
    input.ki.wVk = key; // virtual-key code for left arrow key
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Keep the key held down for a random amount of time
    Sleep((rand() % 5000) + 500);

    // Release the key
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

When I search for that BSOD code 99% of the results have to do with booting or faulty hardware/drivers but literally the only thing that changed on my PC is this program that I wrote. Maybe it's the infinite loop? I'm not sure..

Comment: It should not be possible for a user-mode program on modern Windows versions to single-handedly BSOD.

Comment: Is this repeatable? Have you tried running this program more than once to see if it happens again?

Comment: No user-mode process will ever cause a [Bug Check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450912.aspx). It definitely isn't your program. It *could* be, that your program is responsible for a faulty driver to execute a buggy code path, but the core issue is still a buggy driver, not some user-mode program.

Comment: Use the instructions in the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557408(v=vs.85).aspx) to put together a bug report. You've found a device driver bug.

Comment: This is probably because you're sending an invalid key code.  `key` in `setUpNewKeypress` can be WORD(-1), 0, 1, or 2, as you're subtracting one after the mod when you make the function call.  You also never map that index into a key scancode in `m_KeyList`.

Comment: Oh snap @1201ProgramAlarm I just noticed that as well! So I changed that line to `setUpNewKeypress(m_KeyList[rand() % ARRAYSIZE(m_KeyList)]);`.